# Node.js response without wait some operations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I´m working with myRestFul Api in Node.JS and Moongose.
I have to do some operations, but I need to response to the client the most quickly possible.
For this reason, I have save operations that in fact, I don´t need to include in the response... My point is... I can save a mongo document without wait to finish this operation???.
And it´s possible to do the thing with some https operations...

For example, I want to call to another external service , but I don´t need the response... I only want to make the call.

Example:

this is what I´m doing now:

```
async func test (req,res)
{

   await https.post(data); //i don´t need the response, only make the call

   const user = new User({name: "bob"})
   const other = new Other({title: "hello"})

   await user.save() //I don´t need to wait... only save the document
   await other.save() //I don´t need to wait ... only save the document

   res.send({success : true}) // my response doesn´t need the result of this operations...

}
```

My question is... I can change the last code, for this, without any problem.... for example... the client ends the connection with the server (with res.send()) and all pending operation (such https post)) are cancelled??

```
async func test (req,res)
{

   https.post(data); 

   const user = new User({name: "bob"})
   const other = new Other({title: "hello"})

   user.save()
   other.save()

   res.send({success : true})

}
```

As you can see, really I don´t need in this case to wait any of the operations... but I don´t know if this can cause any problem if the response send happen before the https operations ends or save operations ends...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just send the response, the rest of the code is execute even after sending data until you use return or next(false) after res.send.

Comment: Perhpas move `res.send({success : true})` to before `const user = new User({name: "bob"})`

Comment: But you are telling the client that `success: true` and you dont know if the process ended succesfully. You would be lying :P Is it possible? Yes, but the common sense and the good practice is waiting for the process to finish successfully.

Comment: Yes. I totally agree. I was considering that you said `I don´t need in this case to wait any of the operations..` so that's why I suggested this method. It's true that we shouldn't lie to the clinet xD.

Comment: Have you tried using `.then()`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quickly. Yes in this case it´s a little lie, because I´m saying success true but maybe is not... but for this reason I need to know if this is a valid logic, because in this case we are working with a third party Api and I have another process that later, confirm all this changes... For this reason I don´t need to wait in this point to confirm this steps....